# Rails ActiveStorage how to Fileupload via REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rails-activestorage

How can I upload a file from an external service or app (iOS App, Go App, etc) to a Rails REST API which uses Active Storage local file storage?

All the tutorials I can find use HTML forms. I'd like to upload my files via a POST request to the Rails API. The main thing I am uncertain about is what headers and what kind of format I need to send the files in to the backend.

Comment: Further info that may be helpful: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to just send normal form-data. I used Postman for testing which works great for file uploads as well http://getpostman.com

Comment: Can you include an example?

Comment: Actually, yes could you include an example? This is very interesting; I'm a little confused with "sending normal form-data" with Postman. I also use postman, but I don't know how to do that. I'm interested in sending images to a rails api however, I don't know how I would do that through say a iOS app with swift. Sure I can send a file using postman, but how would I do the same thing with a Javascript app, or a swift or android app?

Comment: needs more detail to be a working solution. An example could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is useful for you, You can decode base64 then generate temp file and upload that file.

Comment: Thanks but base64 will increase the file size by 33% and i really don't want to do that